# Circular segment and a triangle, how to find the angle and the arc length?

Tags: geometry

In the image below, $O$ is the center of the circumference. Compute the value of $\alpha$ and the length of $\stackrel\frown{BC}$.

[image]

Comment: Hint: from the 57° you can immediately find $\alpha$ by a rather standard geometric property of circles

Comment: Just got it. $\alpha = {114}^{o}$, right?

Comment: Yes, that is right, but now the rest is straight forward. Calculate the circumference first